# Problema script BASH linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Hola tengo el siguiente problema:

> Realice un script que mueva todos los programas del directorio actual (archivos ejecutables) hacia el subdirectorio `"bin”` del directorio *HOME* del usuario actualmente logueado.
>
> El script debe imprimir en pantalla los nombres de los que mueve, e indicar cuántos ha movido, o que no ha movido ninguno.
>
> Si el directorio `“bin”` no existe, deberá ser creado.

No sabría como empezar a hacerlo, lo único que hice fue poner una instrucción:

```
if [ !-d $1 ]; then  # Verifico si no es un directorio válido  
    echo "$1 no es un directorio válido"  
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que tu necesitas es iniciar aprendiendo los comando basicos de unix antes de realizar el Script utilizando la instrucción **ls** para listar los archivos del directorio tambien debes tomar en cuenta si necesitas los archivos ocultos **ls -a** y esa lista guardarla en una variable para poder emplear un **for do** y utilizar la instrucción **mv** es el equivalente de windows a utilizar el mouse para **Cortar**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
RUTA_SCRIPT=Donde alojas tu script
RUTA_ORIGEN=ruta de donde estan los archivos
RUTA_DESTINO=ruta de donde seran pegados
cd $RUTA_ORIGEN                              #Muevete a la ruta

#Para listar lo puedes hacer de varias formas te presento dos

#En una Variable
LISTA=ls -ltr       

#En un Archivo
ls -ltr > $RUTA_SCRIPT/lista.txt

for x in `echo $LISTA`                        #Con la variable
for x in `cat $RUTA_SCRIPT/lista.txt`     #Con el Archivo
do
   mv $RUTA_ORIGEN/$x $RUTA_DESTINO
done
```

Es cuestión de probar y aprender para unix solo debes cuidarte de aplicar el comando **rm**